# How to get Google's Oauth screen to load in a window on a Flask app on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, oauth-2.0

I'm building a Python Flask app that gathers some information about the user's Google Tag Manager (GTM) account. To do this, I need them to authorize read only access to their GTM account, and then I go and retrieve the data I need.

The ideal flow here is:

1. User clicks "log in with Google"
2. A new tab opens up asking them to select their Google account
3. The next page tells them what permissions I'm looking for, and to allow access
4. They accept, the auth flow is complete and the tab closes.

I've managed to get the app running locally with the desired flow, no problem.

However, once I deployed it to Heroku, I hit a roadblock, in that the auth flow simply doesn't work. Heroku's logs read:

```
If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter
 --noauth_local_webserver
```

I dug a bit, added `args.noauth_local_webserver = True` as a parameter to the Oauth Flow object.

However, that creates a new problem, where on page load, this shows up in Heroku's logs:

```
Go to the following link in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=629932623162-nguh8ssud6her0e6bbc5vloe1k3aq95q.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ftagmanager.readonly&access_type=offline&response_type=code&prompt=select_account
Enter verification code:
```

This works in my local environment as I can visit that page and paste the verification code into my console, but isn't really useful on Heroku. I'm not sure where I'd paste the verification code, and this certainly doesn't make sense if someone other than me is going to try and log on.

**Does anyone know how I can get the user's web browser to open the auth flow automatically, rather than having it show up in the console?**

If it helps, here's the GetService() function I'm using (pulled from Google's docs):

```
def GetService():

# Parse command-line arguments.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
   parents=[tools.argparser])

flags = parser.parse_args([])
flags.noauth_local_webserver = True

# Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
   client_secrets_path, scope=scope,
   prompt = 'consent', 
   message=tools.message_if_missing(client_secrets_path)) 
   storage = file.Storage(api_name + '.dat')

credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid: 
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

# Build the service object.
service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

return service
```

I then retrieve data from the service object using calls like this:

```
def retrieveAcctList():
    accountObj = GetService().accounts().list(
        access_token = token).execute()
```

which triggers the flow on my local machine.

Any help is appreciated!